# can i query some value in hazelcast map?

Tags: filter, hazelcast

I have a map like("id1","34";"id2","45";"id3","55"...),can I retrieve the key whose value is big than 50,and get the keys whose value are the 3 biggest.Do hazelcast has the filter?Please tell where I can refer to .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazelcast has distributed queries. You can find a whole chapter about it in the documentation: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-query

Comment: OK,I have found the predicate function.Are there any functions can help me to get the top 3 number's key of a map(Imap<String ,recordClass>)  in Hazelcast.The recordClass is "private String Id; private int number;"

Comment: You might want to look into fast aggregations in 3.8 (which is upcoming): https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-reference-manual/blob/master/src/FastAggregations.md